# Move a File from Windows to Linux Server without SCP, PSCP or PSFTP

Tags: files, file-copy, putty

I have a file I need moved from my windows desktop to my linux server. For some reason my colleague cannot get SCP to move the file as we normally would, our servers also don't have PSCP or PSFTP installed on the server or access to install these files. Is there any other way or workaround to move files between the two environments?

Comment: USB flash drive

Comment: While I agree with @jsotola, you should spend some time figuring out why scp is suddenly not working. Is it just this one particular file, or does it affect everything?

Comment: SCP still works fine for me with all files. But I also don't have access to the server my colleague is having troubles with, so I'm not sure if it'd still work for me

Comment: It is possible to disable ssh services on the server. May be this is what happened. Probably some security thing. However you can still move a file via piping it.

Comment: As usual linux distros use openssh, it's possibly a safe bet you can use sftp (which is NOT scp) to copy your file. WinSCP does advertise support for this protocol. Some configurations may restrict a protocol or the other. Different users may also have different configurations.